# Exception while creating Wiki page using CSOM

Tags: c#, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, csom

Using below function I am trying to create wiki Page:

```
 static void CreateWikiPage(ClientContext context, string pageName, string pageContent)
        {
            List wikiPages = context.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("Pages");
            context.Load(wikiPages);
            context.ExecuteQuery();
            context.Load(wikiPages.RootFolder.Files);
            context.ExecuteQuery();
            wikiPages.RootFolder.Files[0].CopyTo(wikiPages.ParentWebUrl + "/Pages/" +  pageName + ".aspx", true);
            wikiPages.RootFolder.Update();
            context.ExecuteQuery();
            context.Load(wikiPages.RootFolder.Files);
            context.Load(wikiPages.RootFolder.Folders);
            context.ExecuteQuery();
            Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.File wikiFile = null;
            var query = new CamlQuery
            {
                ViewXml = "<View><Query><OrderBy><FieldRef Name='ID' Ascending='FALSE'/></OrderBy></Query><RowLimit>1</RowLimit></View>"
            };
            var items = wikiPages.GetItems(query);
            context.Load(items, icol => icol.Include(i => i.File));
            context.ExecuteQuery();
            if (items.Count == 1)
            {
                var pageFile = items[0].File;
                wikiFile = pageFile;
            }  
            ListItem wikiPage = wikiFile.ListItemAllFields;
            wikiPage["WikiField"] = pageContent;
            wikiPage.Update();
            context.ExecuteQuery();

        }
```

I am getting exception: `Cannot invoke method or retrieve property from null object. Object returned by the following call stack is null.`

Comment: Witch line raise error ?

Comment: hi Max, last line giving exception

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error probably occurs since `WikiField` field does not exist in Pages Library. My guess that you are trying to create an `Enterprise Wiki Page` and not a Page in a `Wiki Page Library`. They are not the same, in the fist case it is a *Publishing Page* and the page is based on `Enterprise Wiki Page` layout, in the second it is a *Wiki WebPart Page*.

So, assuming that Enterprise Wiki Page need to be created, below is demonstrated how to accomplish it using CSOM in SharePoint 2010.

### How to create an Enterprise Wiki Page using CSOM in SharePoint 2010

```
public static void CreateWikiPage(ClientContext ctx, string pageName, string pageContent)
{
        const string templateRedirectionPageMarkup = "<%@ Page Inherits=\"Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.TemplateRedirectionPage,Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing,Version=14.0.0.0,Culture=neutral,PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c\" %> <%@ Reference VirtualPath=\"~TemplatePageUrl\" %> <%@ Reference VirtualPath=\"~masterurl/custom.master\" %>";

        var wikiPages = ctx.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("Pages");
        var fileInfo = new FileCreationInformation
            {
                Url = pageName,
                Content = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(templateRedirectionPageMarkup),
                Overwrite = true
            };

        var wikiFile = wikiPages.RootFolder.Files.Add(fileInfo);
        var wikiPage = wikiFile.ListItemAllFields;
        wikiPage["PublishingPageContent"] = pageContent;
        wikiPage["PublishingPageLayout"] = "/_catalogs/masterpage/EnterpriseWiki.aspx, Basic Page";
        wikiPage.Update();
        ctx.ExecuteQuery();
}
```

**Usage**

```
CreateWikiPage(ctx,"Greetings.aspx","Welcome to SharePoint");
```